# PhpStorm IDE: Keyboard Home/Pos1 should move caret to real beginning of the line (character position 0) instead of the beginning of the first word

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard, ide, phpstorm, editor

I'm in the process of switching (with some specific PHP production context) from Sublime Text(4x) to PhpStorm (2022.2).

I am of course trying to migrate as many features/habits as possible, as identical as possible to my new environment. Many things I have managed to do but I have a showstopper when it comes to using/keymapping the Home-/Pos1-Button as I was used to.

##### What I want:

Being somewhere in a line of (PHP) code I want to press the Home-/Pos1-Button to immediately get to the (really) first character(0) of the line which is the widespread default behaviour of that key.

##### What I get (problem):

When I hit that button once PhpStorm IDE moves the caret to the beginning of the first word/non-whitespace character of the current line and I need to hit the key again to really get to the beginning of the line. I have tried a couple of things but I get the feeling this is "intended" non-configurable behaviour...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried googling and configuring Settings > Editor > Keymap in many ways but did not succeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Home moves caret to first non-whitespace character` -> disable.